# Substituting the same number of items in perl regexp one-liner

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a wonky CSV file like this

```
"asdf",,,"asdf","asdf"asdf"
```

and I want to convert the commas to tabs (for personal reasons)

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
perl -ne 's/",+"/\t/g && print'
```

expected output is

```
"asdf[tab][tab][tab]asdf[tab]asdf"asdf"
```

but that only replaces one tab with multiple commas, I need to have 3 commas for 3 tabs.  Is there a way to count the number of matches in one of those existential quantifiers (+ or *) and use that to determine how many tabs I should print

I can handle the beginning and ending quotes, unless someone wants to throw in their destruction.

Comment: Can any of the fields in the CSV possibly contain commas?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes

Comment: @anu I'll stop quoting my code, thanks

Comment: @anubhava I know I have no tabs in the file, but I've got random quotes and commas inside some of the fields (it's a super secure password dump file)

Comment: @anubhava yeah, that's the main problem, why I need to convert the commas to something else and get rid of the quotes altogether so I can open it up in excel

Comment: @anubhava stripping the beginning and ending quotes is good, but trivial.  removing the quote inside `asdf"asdf` would be destroy everything

Comment: yeah, it's perfect, just waiting for the time to pass so I can accept it.

Comment: Why are you removing all of the quotes except the first, the last, and the second-to-last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
perl -pe 's/"(,+)"/"\t" x length($1)/eg'
```

This uses the [`x` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) to produce as many tabs as there were commas.

Answer (score 0):

That replaces all commas with one tab, because you are using `,+` and asking it to match all commas in one go.

Your code:

```
perl -ne 's/",+"/\t/g && print'
```

Problem is the "+". It takes multiple of whatever

I changed it to:

```
perl -ne 's/,/\t/g && print'
```

and it worked fine:

```
"asdf"                  "asdf"  "asdf   "asdf"
```